# How to store a query result into a variable in mysql and then use it another query and echo result?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, echo

I have some complex situation. I have joined multiple tables using `LEFT JOIN` Now I want to store the result of my query in a variable then i want to call this result in my another `SELECT` query to fetch my desired data from `mysql` db. 
 I tried this but i failed.

Using following query i can store result of query in variable `@v1`

```
SET @v1 := (SELECT `opinion_id` FROM `pacra_client_opinion_relations` WHERE `client_id` = 97 LIMIT 1);
```

Now in following query i use variable in which i store result of my 1st query

```
    SELECT @v1, r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN   companies_contact co
ON c.id = co.companies_id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE r.client_id= @v1
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

When i execute this query in my `PhpMyadmin` it show my correct result

[image]

But when i use this query in my PHP page and try to echo some field of my table it does not display any thing.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra1";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

"SET @v1 := (SELECT `opinion_id` FROM `pacra_client_opinion_relations` WHERE `client_id` = 97 LIMIT 1)";
$sql= " SELECT @v1, r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN   companies_contact co
ON c.id = co.companies_id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE r.client_id= @v1
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $liaison_one = $row['liaison_one'];
    echo $liaison_one;

}




?>
```

A blank page is shown in my browser. Please can you suggest me where i am wrong?

Comment: Turn on error reporting,  you do have a space after each line in your query right? (Place: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the top of your php file)

Comment: @Epodax after placing `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` it does not show any thing yet... !!!

Comment: Try with `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: Pro tip. Always do "view source ...." on a blank or confusing web page result; sometimes they have contents that don't show in the browser.

Comment: @Epodax Not working yet

Comment: Echo the $sql from php and then run the echoed query in phpmyadmin

Comment: @OllieJones its only show my Html code. is is not showing tha data which i print using PHP its mean it can not execute my php echo. can you please help me

Comment: @SantoshJagtap My query working fine when i run it in phpMyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables only last for the current mysql "session" so when doing it in PHP the second query is treated as a new session and therefore the variable isn't set.

For example if in phpmyadmin I run:

```
SET @v1 := (SELECT id FROM `mytable` WHERE field='something' LIMIT 1);
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE id = @v1;
```

It works fine.

However if I run:

```
SET @v1 := (SELECT id FROM `mytable` WHERE field='something' LIMIT 1);
```

and then

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE id = @v1;
```

It will return 0 results as @v1 isn't set.

Therefore I would try:

```
$sql = "SET @v1 := (SELECT `opinion_id` FROM `pacra_client_opinion_relations` WHERE `client_id` = 97 LIMIT 1);
SELECT @v1, r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN   companies_contact co
ON c.id = co.companies_id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE r.client_id= @v1
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1";

$conn->multi_query($sql);
$conn->next_result(); //as the first query we don;t need anything from
$result = $conn->use_result();
```

Comment: It show error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\letter\t1.php on line 41`

Comment: `echo $conn->error; `

Should tell you why it couldn't get the results. Do this before the call to fetch_assoc()

Comment: Sorry, you might need to also change:

`$result = $conn->query($sql);`

to

`$result = $conn->multi_query($sql);`

Comment: it show `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @v1, r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_da' at line 2`

Comment: Was that before or after changing `->query($sql);` to `->multi_query($sql);`?

Comment: After changing it show again `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\letter\t1.php on line 42`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86876/discussion-between-neddage-and-sunny).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know mysql's `SET @` syntax, but I see that your code doesn't make sense:

```
"SET @v1 := (SELECT `opinion_id` FROM `pacra_client_opinion_relations` WHERE `client_id` = 97 LIMIT 1)";
$sql= " SELECT @v1, r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.[...]
```

The first line of these two is nothing (has the same effect as a comment). It's a string which is not assigned or executed somehow. You either need to assign it to a variable (`$sql2 = "SET ...")` or execute it using mysql commands

Comment: Can you please Post whole answer. I cant understand what you are saying.

Comment: This was the answer. Your code is running `SELECT @v1` but `@v1` is probably not defined because the line is ignored. You might want to call `$conn->execute("SET @v1 := [...]")` or similar to make your assignment usable with the next SELECT call (again: I never used this syntax and also don't have a working test environment to check my answer)